# Check that the dates are not overlapping

Tags: laravel-6

Check that the date doesn't overlap.
I'm creating a site for an employee leave management, where an employee wants to apply for a leave and the leaves can not overlap.
programming lang: laravel 6, jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(StartA <= EndB) and (EndA >= StartB)**

Proof:
Let ConditionA Mean that DateRange A Completely After DateRange B
_                        |---- DateRange A ------| 
|---Date Range B -----|                           _
(True if StartA > EndB)

Let ConditionB Mean that DateRange A is Completely Before DateRange B
|---- DateRange A -----|                       _ 
 _                          |---Date Range B ----|
(True if EndA < StartB)

Then Overlap exists if Neither A Nor B is true -
(If one range is neither completely after the other,
nor completely before the other, then they must overlap.)

Now one of **[De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)** says that:

Not (A Or B) <=> Not A And Not B

Which translates to: (StartA <= EndB)  and  (EndA >= StartB)